# Hiding/Showing Child Windows of a Tab Control Win32

Tags: c, winapi

To be clear, I am coding in win32 and am not using MFC, wxWidgets or .net.

My issue is that I have a tab control with 2 tabs. For debugging purposes, each tab has a single `STATIC` window. When initialising, the following code is run:

```
 createTabControl();
 CreateStaticViewTab1();
 CreateStaticViewTab1();
 ShowWindow(Task1Tab, SW_SHOW);
```

Where

```
void createTabControl(){
    TCITEM tie = { 0 };  
    hWndInputTab = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, L"Input", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD , 10, 40, 300, 650, hWnd, (HMENU)TAB_INPUT, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
    SetDefaultFont(hWndInputTab);

    tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT; 

    TCHAR pszTab1[] = L"TAB 1";  
    tie.pszText = pszTab1;  
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(hWndInputTab, 0, &tie)

    TCHAR pszTab2[] = L"TAB 2"; 
    tie.pszText = pszTab2;  
    TabCtrl_InsertItem(hWndInputTab, 1, &tie)
}

void CreateStaticViewTab1(){

    Task1Tab = CreateWindowEx(0,L"STATIC",L"Static Control on Tab1",WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER | SS_CENTERIMAGE,  75, 75, 200, 60, hWndInputTab,NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),NULL);

    SetDefaultFont(Task1Tab);
}

void CreateStaticViewTab2(){

    Task1Tab = CreateWindowEx(0,L"STATIC",L"Static Control on Tab2",WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER | SS_CENTERIMAGE,  75, 75, 200, 60, hWndInputTab,NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE),NULL);

    SetDefaultFont(Task2Tab);
}
```

In the `WndProc`, I am handling the `WM_NOTIFY` message. I have checked and can confirm that it executes correctly, calling the appropriate functions (`ShowTab1()` and `ShowTab2()`).

These two functions are designed to show and hide the appropriate tabs when the selection changes. They do so by the following:

```
void ShowTab1(){
    ShowWindow(Task2Tab, SW_HIDE);
    ShowWindow(Task1Tab, SW_SHOW);
}

void ShowTab2(){
    ShowWindow(Task1Tab, SW_HIDE);
    ShowWindow(Task2Tab, SW_SHOW);
}
```

These should - as I understand it - hide and show the correct tabs as appropriate.

My issue is that when the program is loaded, the correct tab (1) is shown. When tab 2 is clicked, the content of tab 1 (`Task1Tab`) is correctly hidden, however, the content of tab 2 (`Task2Tab`) is not correctly shown. When returning to tab 1, `Task1Tab` is correctly shown.

I cannot identify why there is a difference between the two pieces of code, as they are virtually identical.

nb. I have tested the code without the `ShowWindow(Task1Tab, SW_SHOW)` in the initialisation, this creates the tabs without any content and when tab 2 is clicked, nothing is shown, however, when tab 1 is clicked, `Task1Tab` is correctly shown.

Comment: You never call `CreateStaticViewTab2`. You call `CreateStaticViewTab1` twice. `Task2Tab` is never assigned. Or is this code fake? My advice, produce a [mcve] so that we have confidence that we are looking at the same code as you.

Comment: No, you're completely correct. Oops!

Comment: It's also time to stop using `TCHAR`. Your code targets Unicode. Use `wchar_t`. Don't pretend that your code can target ANSI. It cannot.

Comment: I've now corrected the typo and have replaced my TCHAR with whar_t and everything is working perfectly. Thank-you for your help!

Comment: @Olaf No, WinAPI can be consumed by many languages, including both C and C++.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, by defining _UNICODE or UNICODE, doesn't **TCHAR** becomes wchar?

Comment: @Joel `wchar_t` you mean. But what happens when you don't have those defined. Then it is `char` and then the code in the question does not compile. `TCHAR` was for being able to target both Windows 95/98/ME and Windows NT from one code base. Now that 95/98/ME are long dead, it serves no useful purpose.

Comment: Well, you can easy change **char** to **TCHAR**, defined _UNICODE the compiler will be using the proper wchar_t or char type. I agree ANSI is old and deprecated in this days, but some users like to copy paste stuff around the web to test with modern compilers. Using TCHAR and defined UNICODE can be portable on any compiler. UNICODE is present, As far I know since vc++ 6.0, so everyone will be happy as far they use TCHAR and not direct char type. My $0.02.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have been caught out by some routine copy/paste errors. You call `CreateStaticViewTab1` twice and never call `CreateStaticViewTab2`. And both `CreateStaticViewTab1` and `CreateStaticViewTab2` assign to `Task1Tab`. These mistakes would explain the behaviour that you observe.

Were your code to have performed any error checking, then that would have led you to the problem. Checking for errors would have revealed that `ShowWindow(Task2Tab, ...)` was failing because of an invalid window handle. So, another important lesson, beyond taking more care with the clipboard, is that you should always check for errors when calling Windows API functions.

Answer (score 0):

Obvious issue - `CreateStaticViewTab2()` was never called.